# Creating a dropdown list trough column after pasting values into worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm trying to create a dropdown list trough the whole column after the new data is pasted into the worksheet. So, the pasting action would trigger the creating of the dropdown list in the last column.
For now I have wrote the code, but it's not working. Any help?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Rng As Range, r1 As Range
Set Rng = Range("AQ7:AQ10000")
If Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each r1 In Rng
r1.Select
 With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=YES"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
 End With
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Static List Values`: you should use `Formula1:="Yes,No"`.

For `Dynamic List Values`: First store the drop down list in `cells` and then use the same. Or you can also define `named range` and then use it in `Formula`.

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Sheet1!B1:B6"
```